# Calling appsettings.json file of another solution from Azure Functions in .net core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-functions

I am using dependency injection in my Azure Function to access my functions in another solution. At one point, I am also calling IEmailSender function to send an e-mail. when doing so, I am using my values from **appsettings.json that is in my other solution**. However, when I call the function to send an e-mail, the program does not see my appsettings values, and returns null or 0 (Options.SmtpHost, Options.SmtpPort etc...)

How would I be able to read my appsettings.json when called from Azure Functions in .net core?

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = Options.SmtpHost,
            Port = Options.SmtpPort,
            EnableSsl = true,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Options.SmtpUsername, Options.SmtpPassword),
        };
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(Options.From, Options.DisplayName);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You mean another solution or just project?

Comment: From other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've 2 solutions like

1. AppService (.net core class library) - you have implemented Email Sender Service and  reading parameters from appsetting.json
2. Function (.net core Azure Function) - This function project is your application entry point and you added appService reference on this project.

If my assumption is correct, you have to add all appsetting.json value in function local.setting.json.

If my understanding is incorrect, pls add some sample on GitHub to understand better.